# Truecrypt encrypted disk corrupted after moving files to it

Tags: truecrypt

I have a 3 TB disk that I have encrypted using Truecrypt 7.1a on Windows 7 x64. Recently, I had about 700 GB free and was moving about 200 GB of files to it. When the transfer was about 90 % complete Windows showed an error message that it wasn't possible to move a certain file since it was corrupt. I retried a couple of times and then skipped it. The rest of the transfer went ok.

After that, a lot of the files on the encrypted disk was unreadable. Some files still worked, and it wasn't just the newly moved files that was corrupted.
After I had dismounted the disk and tried to mount it again Truecrypt wouldn't let me. Wrong password or not a Truecrypt volume.

After I restored the volume header from an external backup Truecrypt mounts the volume, but Windows says that the disk doesn't contain a recognized file system.
This has happened once before, but I chalked it up to bad luck and maybe related to a re-installation of Windows, but now I know this isn't the case.

Does anyone have any idea about what went wrong and what I can do about it?

Comment: One of the risks of encryption and the reason today when using Truecrypt I copy>verify>delete as appose to move. Sometimes "**it" happens and for no apparent reason! Been there, done that, and remember that sick to my stomach feeling when my stuff simply was gone...

Comment: [TrueCrypt Forum](http://forums.truecrypt.org/) might help to offer a clue why...

Comment: TrueCrypt Forum might help to offer a clue why...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an external hard drive, it is possible that the external hard drive went to sleep during the file transfer. This would cause corruption in the truecrypt file and the files within the container. I use fastcopy to verify that the files have been copied over correctly.